# Composition of functions which is one-to-one.

Tags: real-analysis, functions

$f:Y\rightarrow Z$ and $g:X\rightarrow Y$

If $f\circ g$ is one-to-one then which of the following must be true?

1.$g\circ f$ is one-to-one.

2.g is one-to-one.

3.f is one-to-one.

4.g is onto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct answer is 2.

Assume that $g$ is not 1-1. Then there exist $x,y \in X$ such that $g(x) = g(y)$. But then also $(f\circ g)(x) = f(g(x)) = f(g(y)) = (f\circ g)(y)$.

Comment: Yes you are right thanks

Comment: @xen please refrain from giving complete answers to what are highly likely homework problems stated without showing any effort whatsoever on the part of OP.